# A difficult integer matrix problem

Tags: number-theory, matrix-calculus

$A$ is an integer matrix with size $m \times n$ and $p$ is a prime. Suppose for any non-zero vector $x_{n \times 1}$ with $x_i= 0 \text{ or } 1$, $Ax \neq 0_{m \times 1} \text{ mod } p$. Prove there exists a vector $y_{m \times 1}$ satisfying that: for $z=A^Ty $, all $z_i \neq 0 \text{ mod }p$  $(i =1,...,n)$.

Comment: How does one define a vector $v_{m\times 1}$ taken $\mod p$? Do you mean the $m\times 1$ zero matrix by $0$ when you say $Ax\neq 0\mod p$?

Comment: Yes exactly: $v \mod p$ means all elements $v_i \mod p$, and in $Ax \neq 0$ the 0 is a $m \times 1$ vector.

Answer (score 0):

These are my thoughts so far, it's *not* a complete answer.

We look at $A\mod p$ instead of $A$ without loss of generality. This makes sure every element of $A$ is in $\{0,1,\cdots,p-1\}$.

First of all, note that, if *not* every row of $A$ contains a $0$, then not every column of $A^T$ contains a $0$ (let's say that's the $i$th column), and as such, we pick $y$ to be the $m\times 1$ zero-matrix, but with a $1$ at the the $i$th index. It is clear that then all elements of $A^Ty$ are nonzero.

Thus, we may assume every row of $A$ contains a $0$.

Comment: Yes, we can assume every row of $A$ contains a 0,  but seems it's far from the final proof.

Comment: @DanielB, I just thought I'd share my thoughts. Might help you or someone else with this or a similar problem. And I posted it as an answer since it was a little too long for a comment

Comment: Thanks! Anyone can help this problem? It troubles me for quite a few days...